# "Variable has not been declared" error with variable declared in satisfies clause

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following code:

```
let $pl := doc("playlist.xml")//Song
for $s in $pl
where some $c in $s/Comment satisfies contains($s/Comment, "LP")
return $c/Album
```

And when I try to run it, it outputs an error:
`Variable $c has not been declared`, I got I should return `$s/Album`. Is this error due to a scope of variable? How does it work?

The XML file is:

```
<PlaylistCollection>
  <Playlist name="Piano Jazz" numberOfEntries="2">
  <Entries>
    <Song filename="israel.mp3" songID="israel" 
     artist="bevans">
       <Title>Israel</Title>
       <Album>Explorations</Album>
       <Year>1961</Year>
       <Comment>From the original LP</Comment>
       <Genre>Jazz</Genre>
    </Song>
    <Song filename="debby.mp3" songID="debby" artist="bevans">
       <Title>Waltz For Debby</Title>
       <Album>Waltz For Debby</Album>
       <Year>1961</Year>
       <Genre>Jazz</Genre>
    </Song>
   </Entries>
  </Playlist>
  <Artist artistID="bevans" songs="israel debby">
    <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
    <LastName>Evans</LastName>
  </Artist>
</PlaylistCollection>
```

In this case `$c` is useless, or not?

Comment: It isn't useless at all, you just can't use it in the `return` part. It would be simpler if you explained what your query is supposed to do.

Comment: Query: retunr every Albums that have a Song that has a comment containing the string "LP". I sait it is useless because I'm not using it directly, it only lets me use the quantifier, right?

Comment: For that purpose, a simple XPath expression is enough: `doc("playlist.xml")//Song[contains(Comment,"LP")]/Album`. XQuery is more  suited for complicated searches.

Answer (score 2):

*I replaced all single letter variables by speaking names. Single letter variables make it horribly hard to understand what's going on for all others (and also you two weeks after writing the code), and make it also more complicated to reference them in the text explaining the code.*

### Scope of Variable Declaration

The XQuery expression `some ... in ... satisfies ...`  and `all ... in ... satisfies ...` are considered to work in another way. In your case, `$c` is only bound in the `satisfies` clause. Instead of

```
where some $comment in $song/Comment satisfies contains($song/Comment, "LP")
```

you could have written

```
where some $comment in $song/Comment satisfies contains($comment, "LP")
```

#### Visibility

Also reconsider the scope: the expression in the `where` clause is a *subexpression*, which means variable declarations in there would hide those of the flwor expression, but are not visible any more after the subexpression was evaluated.

### Implicit Loops

Also, the binding `in` should not be compared with a `let` expression, but is more powerful and can do implicit loops. This will be especially useful in case of multiple songs. For example, if all you want to do is testing whether there exists any song with multiple comments, you could do

```
some $song in $songs satisfies count($song/comment) > 1
```

which implicitly loops over all `$songs` and tests whether one of them satisfies the condition.

### Effective Boolean Value

XQuery knows a concept named effective boolean value. Among other things, this can be used to distinguish empty sequences from those having contents. With other words, you could replace

```
where some $comment in $song/Comment satisfies contains($comment, "LP")
```

with

```
where $song/Comment[contains(., "LP")]
```

. As soon as there is one comment containing LP, the sequence is not empty any more and the filter expression evaluates to `true`.

### Plain XPath 1.0 is Completely Sufficient for the Query

Finally, a simply XPath expression would also do in this case. Predicates are very powerful, and usually result in easier to read code.

```
doc("playlist.xml")//Song[contains(Comment,"LP")]/Album
```

Or in plain text: in `playlist.xml`, look up the songs and filter for those having a comment containing LP. Return their album names.